# How do I download a pdf document from html in rails for a custom path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, wicked-pdf

I am trying to figure out how to download a pdf document from the standard html template. 
I am using wicked pdf gem to generate the PDF.

I followed the instructions in `bundle install` and set up the config according to
https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf

following this, I am trying to make it work for a custom route. It keeps rendering `HTML` instead of delivering `PDF` as specified in the form

What am i doing wrong? Is there a better way to route it to the pdf download?

config/routes.rb

```
  match "/profile" => "vacancies#profile", via: :get
```

view

```
<%= form_for(@vacancy, :url => profile_path, :html => {:method => :get, :format => 'pdf'}) do |f| %>
  <%= submit_tag "Export Profile"%>
<%end%>
```

vacancies_controller

```
def profile
  respond_to do |format|
     format.html{
       render :layout => false
     }
     format.pdf do
       render :pdf => "temp"
       render :layout => false
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: It is somewhat unusual to submit a form with a get request, but maybe it is appropriate anyway. As I have not meddled with `:html` options in `GET` forms it would be appropriate to show the resulting `HTML`, the `params` hash you get in the request and some info if the `HTML` you receive looks like your regular `profile` of if it has something to do what with what lies in `temp`.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a second action following some research, now the download link(in view) works

```
  def download 
     html = render_to_string(:action => :resume, :layout => false) 
     pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html) 
     send_data(pdf, 
         :filename    => "temp.pdf", 
         :disposition => 'attachment') 
  end
```

config/routes.rb

```
match "/download_profile" => "vacancies#download", via: :get
```

view

```
<%= link_to "Export Profile", download_profile_path"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example that you get the idea for download pdf. Follow these steps.

Gemfile

```
gem 'wicked_pdf'
```

**Run this command : $ bundle**
view

```
  = link_to('Download Notes', export_notes_path(id: current_participant.id, format: :pdf), target: '_blank')
```

config/routes.rb

```
get '/export_notes/:id' => 'participant/notes#export_notes', as: :export_notes
```

controller.rb

```
def export_notes
   # Export PDF
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: 'notes',
               template: 'participant/notes/notes_pdf.html.haml',
               dpi: '96',
               :show_as_html                   => params[:debug].present?,
               disable_internal_links: true, disable_external_links: true,
               :print_media_type => false, :no_background => false
        return
      end
    end
  end
```

participant/notes/

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{"http-equiv" => "Content-Type", :content => "text/html; charset=utf-8"}
  %body
    #wrap
      %header
      %main{:role => "main"}
        .main-container
          .main-container-inner
            .main-content
              .page-content
                .page-header
                  %h1.text-center
                  %b Notes
```